# Sum multi dimensional array based on a key in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have mutiple arrays say for now 2, first array has Cities(Mumbai, Pune. Bangalore, Hyderabad)
And 2nd array has Mumbia nad Hyderabd.

I want to sum up the values based on the Key.

Array
(
    [Mumbai] => Array
        (
            [ga:pageviews] => 1
            [ga:visits] => 1
            [ga:newVisits] => 1
            [ga:pageviewsPerVisit] => 1
            [ga:entranceBounceRate] => 1
            [ga:avgTimeOnSite] => 1
            [ga:timeOnSite] => 1
            [ga:bounces] => 1
        )

```
[Pune] => Array
    (
        [ga:pageviews] => 2
        [ga:visits] => 2
        [ga:newVisits] => 2
        [ga:pageviewsPerVisit] => 2
        [ga:entranceBounceRate] => 2
        [ga:avgTimeOnSite] => 2
        [ga:timeOnSite] => 2
        [ga:bounces] => 2
    )

[Bangalore] => Array
    (
        [ga:pageviews] => 3
        [ga:visits] => 3
        [ga:newVisits] => 3
        [ga:pageviewsPerVisit] => 3
        [ga:entranceBounceRate] => 3
        [ga:avgTimeOnSite] => 3
        [ga:timeOnSite] => 3
        [ga:bounces] => 3
    )

[Hyderabad] => Array
    (
        [ga:pageviews] => 4
        [ga:visits] => 4
        [ga:newVisits] => 4
        [ga:pageviewsPerVisit] => 4
        [ga:entranceBounceRate] => 4
        [ga:avgTimeOnSite] => 4
        [ga:timeOnSite] => 4
        [ga:bounces] => 4
    )
```

)

2nd Array:

Array
(
    [Mumbai] => Array
        (
            [ga:pageviews] => 5
            [ga:visits] => 5
            [ga:newVisits] => 5
            [ga:pageviewsPerVisit] => 5
            [ga:entranceBounceRate] => 5
            [ga:avgTimeOnSite] => 5
            [ga:timeOnSite] => 5
            [ga:bounces] => 5
        )

```
[Hyderabad] => Array
    (
        [ga:pageviews] => 2
        [ga:visits] => 2
        [ga:newVisits] => 2
        [ga:pageviewsPerVisit] => 2
        [ga:entranceBounceRate] => 2
        [ga:avgTimeOnSite] => 2
        [ga:timeOnSite] => 2
        [ga:bounces] => 2
    )
```

)

I want the result as:

Array
(
    [Mumbai] => Array
        (
            [ga:pageviews] => 6
            [ga:visits] => 6
            [ga:newVisits] => 6
            [ga:pageviewsPerVisit] => 6
            [ga:entranceBounceRate] => 6
            [ga:avgTimeOnSite] => 6
            [ga:timeOnSite] => 6
            [ga:bounces] => 6
        )

```
[Pune] => Array
    (
        [ga:pageviews] => 2
        [ga:visits] => 2
        [ga:newVisits] => 2
        [ga:pageviewsPerVisit] => 2
        [ga:entranceBounceRate] => 2
        [ga:avgTimeOnSite] => 2
        [ga:timeOnSite] => 2
        [ga:bounces] => 2
    )

[Bangalore] => Array
    (
        [ga:pageviews] => 3
        [ga:visits] => 3
        [ga:newVisits] => 3
        [ga:pageviewsPerVisit] => 3
        [ga:entranceBounceRate] => 3
        [ga:avgTimeOnSite] => 3
        [ga:timeOnSite] => 3
        [ga:bounces] => 3
    )

[Hyderabad] => Array
    (
        [ga:pageviews] => 6
        [ga:visits] => 6
        [ga:newVisits] => 6
        [ga:pageviewsPerVisit] => 6
        [ga:entranceBounceRate] => 6
        [ga:avgTimeOnSite] => 6
        [ga:timeOnSite] => 6
        [ga:bounces] => 6
    )
```

)

Thanks for your help....
Ruth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($arr2["Hyderabad"] as $key => $val)
{
    $arr1["Hyderabad"][$key] += $val;
}
```

That should do it for you :)

Comment: I'm sure you mean `+=` to sum the values rather than concatenating them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$newarray = $array1;
foreach ($array2 as $key => $values) {
    foreach ($values as $name => $value) {
        if (!is_array($newarray[$key])) { $newarray[$key] = array(); }
        $newarray[$key][$name] += $value;
    }
}

// $newarray should now be the array you want with values added
```

Answer (score 0):

lets us say all this in an array named parent

```
$parent has keys as 0,1


foreach($parent as $k=>$v)    
{
     foreach($v as $ik=>$iv)
     {
          foreach($iv as $fk=>$fv)
          {
              $cities[$ik][$fk] = $cities[$ik[$fk]+$fv;
          }
     }
 }
```